# Why can't I import some libraries with jspm and typescript and can with others?

Tags: typescript, typescript1.6

I've a behavior I don't understand when i try to import some library i configured with jspm.

Some work perfectly like

```
import * as React from 'react'; 
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; 
import {FlatButton} from 'material-ui';
```

But others not at all :

```
import {FormControls} from 'react-bootstrap'
import {somethng} from 'react-toolbox'`
import * as boostrap from 'boostrap'
```

all these libraries have been downloaded by jspm without any problem but refuse to be imported in typescript...

Is there something I've done wrong? Any clue?

Comment: There is a typo in bootstrap + are you also having the type definitions for all those libs?

Answer (score 0):

It was, as you mentionned, the lack of ambient declaration which triggered the problem.

We can summurize all the import process as follows.

Import statement does actually to things:

- import the "specification" of the module we want to import, i.e. the "contract" of the imported module. This contract may be found from the ts code we write itself, and also from declaration files (d.ts) which may be provided through for instance tds. This specification is used by the compiler to ensure the code is correcly typed, and by tools to provide intellisense.
- import actual code when the application runs, enabling then an incremental download of the module during the app running

Moreover, the modules may be accessed in two way :

- in a relative manner, i.e. wrt the location of the code being importing another module, e.g.  import {Dummy} from './dummy'
- in an absolute manner, i.e. from the application root. Doping this, the compiler will scan all the subdirectories to find the right specified module, and then try to load it

We generally use the first option when we try to access modules described in the application itself, i.e. the ts code we write 
We generally use the second option when we import code from a vendor module like react, jquery, bootstrap, .... We usually use the tsd tool to import an already generated module description, and these declarations files are automatiocally put into the "typing" subdirectory. Parallely we need to downaload actual code in order to make the application running ; we may do this (for instance if we use the "system" compilation option) by using the jspm tool which will download the js files into the jspm_packages subdirectoy.

If we downloaded by jspm for instance a js module which has not yet a d.ts declaration file, we will have to define one. I propose to put it also in the "typings" sub directory generated initially by tsd.

The declaration file may be defined in many ways, but we may simplify by using the two following manners :

- use the "export" statement in a given file, e.g.
  //file dummy.d.ts
  export class Dummy {
     name : string
  }

and importing in a file by :

```
import {Dummy} from 'dummy'
```

- using the "module" statement

  //file dummy.d.ts
  declare module "mydummy" {
     export class Dummy {
      ...
     }
  }

and importing it in another file by :

```
import {Dummy} fom 'mydummy'
```

If the two ways may seem quite similar, the second approach enables to declare the same "mydummy" module in separate files, the compiler merging all the declaration automatically. We may notice that in the second approach the name of the module is not the name of the file, as in was in the first approach.